# Android partially persistent savedInstanceState

Tags: java, android, xml, oncreate

I have an android fragment that only restores the last portion of a class object when the orientation changes.  My code is below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        // Load the weapon content specified by the fragment
        mWeapon = EquipmentContent.WEAPON_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);

    // get reference to the ImageViews
    weaponImageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
    groupImageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.groupSymbol);
    individualImageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.individualSymbol);

    // get a reference to the linear layout
    statLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.statLinearLayout);

    if (mWeapon != null) {

        AssetManager assets = getActivity().getAssets();
        InputStream pictureStream;
        InputStream groupStream;
        InputStream individualStream;

        try
        {
           // get an InputStream to the asset representing the next picture
            pictureStream = assets.open("Pictures/" + mWeapon.picture + ".png");

            // load the asset as a Drawable and display on the ImageView
            Drawable picture = Drawable.createFromStream(pictureStream, mWeapon.picture);
            weaponImageView.setImageDrawable(picture);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("MainFragment", "Error loading " + mWeapon.picture + ".png", e);
        }
        try
        {
            // get an InputStream to the asset representing the next picture
            groupStream = assets.open("Group/" + mWeapon.group + ".png");

            // load the asset as a Drawable and display on the ImageView
            Drawable group = Drawable.createFromStream(groupStream, mWeapon.group);
            groupImageView.setImageDrawable(group);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("MainFragment", "Error loading " + mWeapon.group + ".png", e);
        }
        try
        {
            // get an InputStream to the asset representing the next picture
            individualStream = assets.open("Individual/" + mWeapon.individual + ".png");

            // load the asset as a Drawable and display on the ImageView
            Drawable individual = Drawable.createFromStream(individualStream, mWeapon.individual);
            individualImageView.setImageDrawable(individual);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("MainFragment", "Error loading " + mWeapon.individual + ".png", e);
        }
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail)).setText(mWeapon.id); // Sets the title text of the fragment
        populateStatistics(inflater);


    }
    return rootView;
}

public void populateStatistics(LayoutInflater inflater) {
    // TODO: currently reverts all EditText views to the last input upon orientation change
    if (!mWeapon.priWeapon.equals("null")) { // if the primary weapon is not null, then inflate relevant TextViews
        TableLayout priWeaponIDTableLayout = (TableLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.statistics_text_view, null); // Weapon title statistic
        statLinearLayout.addView(priWeaponIDTableLayout);
        ((TextView) priWeaponIDTableLayout.findViewById(R.id.category)).setText(R.string.priWeapon);
        ((EditText) priWeaponIDTableLayout.findViewById(R.id.statistic)).setText(String.format("%s", mWeapon.priWeapon));
        TableLayout priWeaponRangeTableLayout = (TableLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.statistics_text_view, null); // Weapon range statistic
        statLinearLayout.addView(priWeaponRangeTableLayout);
        ((TextView) priWeaponRangeTableLayout.findViewById(R.id.category)).setText(R.string.priMaxRange);
        ((TextView) priWeaponRangeTableLayout.findViewById(R.id.category)).setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        ((TextView) priWeaponRangeTableLayout.findViewById(R.id.statistic)).setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        ((EditText) priWeaponRangeTableLayout.findViewById(R.id.statistic)).setText(String.format("%s meters", mWeapon.priMaximumRange));
        TableLayout priWeaponPenTableLayout = (TableLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.statistics_text_view, null); // Weapon penetration statistic
        statLinearLayout.addView(priWeaponPenTableLayout);
        ((TextView) priWeaponPenTableLayout.findViewById(R.id.category)).setText(R.string.priPen);
        ((TextView) priWeaponPenTableLayout.findViewById(R.id.category)).setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        ((TextView) priWeaponPenTableLayout.findViewById(R.id.statistic)).setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        ((EditText) priWeaponPenTableLayout.findViewById(R.id.statistic)).setText(String.format("%s mm", mWeapon.priPenetration));
    }
```

}

The custom layout that I inflate and modify is below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
    <!-- Table Row 0 -->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/priWeapon" android:textColor="#000" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/statistic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/NA" android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:longClickable="false"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Almost everything loads fine when the orientation changes, to include the title, the picture .png, the group and individual .pngs, the weapon id, and the weapon penetration statistic.  The problem is that the weapon penetration statistic replaces the primary weapon id and maximum range for some reason.  I'm not exactly sure why.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tinkered with my code and changed the common flawed denominator view type, 'EditText', to 'TextView'.  It now retains the data that it's supposed to.  For some reason EditText savedInstanceState isn't persistent but TextView is.  I was using EditText originally because the Dietel book I was using used it for the benefit of the underline it provided.  Now I'll just have to create a custom background to replicate that underline and apply it in the XML.